# Elements being re-rendered with the same props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

I have a table with table rows of 500. Each row is a separate component.

The source data for the table is a simple array of objects. Rows need to be dragged, and every time I drag over another row, I change the source data shifting the item inside of the array.

The data is immutable, so every time I'm dealing with a new array.

The problem is: every time the data gets changed, the whole 500 elements are re-rendered. That's a bit of unexpected behavior, because keys for the most of elements stay the same, and React is supposed to optimize the update.

`shouldComponentUpdate` solves the problem, but I'm using mobx and it creates its own implementation of `sCU`, so I can't implement my own `sCU` because it breaks down the mobx flow.

I have a feeling that it should work correctly even without `sCU`.

```
<Table>
    {data.map(item => {
      <TableRow key={item[keyField]} item={item} {...props}/>
    })}
</Table>
```

Any thoughts about this folks?

---UPDATE---

Both components are observers. I've changed my structure like this:

```
// Table component @observer 

@observable 
data = [] 

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) { 
    this.data = [...nextProps.data] 
} 

@action.bound 
onDrag() { 
    // drag handler here which mutates this.data 
    this.data.splice(...) 
} 

render() { 
    return this.data.map(item => (
        <TableRow key={item[keyField]} item={item} {...props} onDrag={this.onDrag}/>
    ))
}
```

But it gives the exact same result, 500 renders when drag

Comment: What is the surrounding context? What components are marked as `@observer`s? But in general, IIRC, MobX would likely prefer mutable, observable state, this being one reason why. See, for example, https://iconof.com/best-practices-for-mobx-with-react/#3-embrace-mutability and https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx/issues/538.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to format the code inside a comment

Comment: You don't, you update the question :)

Answer (score 0):

> The data is immutable, so every time I'm dealing with a new array.

This is the answer. If it's a new array then the whole `TableContainer` component (or whatever you call it, one which is referencing `data` array) is going to react to it and re-render.

> because keys for the most of elements stay the same, and React is supposed to optimize the update.

If key and component type did not change then React won't re-mount them but they will re-render anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In other words, in this case react doesn't care if the props or keys changed or not, it will re-render the component anyway? I made the source data mutable, but result was still the same, 500 renders. I got rid of mobx in the TableRow component, and with `this.state` and `shoudComponentUpdate` it works well. It's not the best solution for me, but at least it works as expected.

Comment: If component does not have `sCU` hook (or analog, like `memo`) it will always re-render if Parent component re-renders. If its key changed too then it is gonna not just re-render but also re-mount completely.

Comment: Table still re-renders because you still referencing each data item inside `.map`, so even if you move some items inside without modifying array it is gonna observe and react to this change.